# How to change microphone device in Android Virtual Device on Mac?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm using bluetooth headset and it has its microphone.

My system sound setting on host is bluetooth output and usb microphone input.

But AVD just record and playback with my bluetooth headset.

I want to change the device to record from the host.

AVD should record from another device from host, the USB microphone.